# Make getFilesDir() non removeable

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to generate and save a `UUID` for each device at the fist time that app get run.
I saved this `UUID` to a file through `getFilesDir()`, but the problem is if user delete my application cache through android setting the above file will be removed too! is there any way to protect the mentioned file from removal process or Is there any better approach?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

You can write it to SD card and hope it is not removed or you can query the device for unique info (imsi, imei...) and store it on your server, and then query your server if the info is missing.

The user should be able to completely remove all data from an app.

Comment: I agree with you about SD-Card, but SD card files can get viewed by every user!

Comment: Absolutely: you can encrypt it if this is a concern to you.